# Check if all HTML Selects were selected using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've a form in HTML with several inputs and some of them are "select"...
All the inputs are mandatory and therefore I need to check if alll have a value...
For that purpose all the "select" element have an "n.d." option with value=0 selected by default...
And the "save" button is "disabled"..

I would like to use JQuery to check if all the "select" have an option "selected" with a value different from 0, and if so, "enable" the "save" button...

Comment: and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) ? GOD and SO help those how help themselves :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var allSelect = $('select').filter(function() {
    return this.value != 0 ;
}).length === $('select').length;
$(':submit').prop('disabled', !allSelect);
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/u8MPr/6/)**